# tcblistof, book class and vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tcolorbox

It deals with the displaying of the tcblistof feature with the package tcolorbox, which differs from the classic `\listoffigures` when used with the book class.
In the example below (with `tcolorbox v 3.05`), you can see vertical space added between chapters inside the List of Figures, but not inside the List of Theorems.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=thm]{theo}{Theorem}{}{}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures{}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{thm}{List of Theorems}

\chapter{Chapter No1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No2}
\end{figure}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No1}{}
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No2}{}
\end{theo}

\chapter{Chapter No2}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No4}
\end{figure}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No3}{}
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No4}{}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same displaying for both? (more precisely, I'd like to make tcblistof behave like the List of Figures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to teach `\chapter` to add the vertical space also in the list of theorems as it does for the lists of figures and tables.

The easiest way is patching `\@chapter` with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=thm]{theo}{Theorem}{}{}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\chaptermark{#1}}% search
  {\chaptermark{#1}\addtocontents{thm}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% replace
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures{}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{thm}{List of Theorems}

\chapter{Chapter No1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No2}
\end{figure}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No1}{}
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No2}{}
\end{theo}

\chapter{Chapter No2}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure No4}
\end{figure}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No3}{}
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}{Theorem No4}{}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have more lists, you can use just one patch instead of many:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\chaptermark{#1}}% search
  {\chaptermark{#1}\@addvspaceinlists}% replace
  {}{}

\newcommand\@addvspaceinlists{%
  \@for\next:=\listoftocs\do{%
    \addtocontents{\next}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\listoftocs{thm}
% in an ideal world it would be
% \renewcommand\listoftocs{lot,lof,thm}
\makeatother
```

Just define `\listoftocs` to a comma separated list with the file extensions pertaining to each list.

Comment: Works fine for me.
@ThomasF.Sturm (if you see this post): could it be implemented in tcolorbox?

Comment: Just for the sake of completness, if `hyperref` is loaded, this works only is it is loaded after the patch. In case `hyperref` has to be loaded before (e.g. if it is loaded by the class), it should be enough to use `\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{thm}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother`